# How to fit data that looks like a gaussian?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I am quite new to statistics, so please forgive me for using probably the wrong vocabulary.

I have some data that looks (to me) like a gaussian when plotted.

The data is an extract from a jpeg image. It's a vertical line taken from the image, and only the Red data is used (from RGB).

Here is the full data (27 data points):

```
> r
 [1] 0.003921569 0.031372549 0.023529412 0.015686275 0.003921569 0.027450980
 [7] 0.003921569 0.015686275 0.031372549 0.105882353 0.305882353 0.490196078
[13] 0.560784314 0.615686275 0.592156863 0.505882353 0.364705882 0.227450980
[19] 0.050980392 0.031372549 0.019607843 0.054901961 0.031372549 0.015686275
[25] 0.027450980 0.003921569 0.011764706

> dput(r)
c(0.00392156862745098, 0.0313725490196078, 0.0235294117647059, 
0.0156862745098039, 0.00392156862745098, 0.0274509803921569, 
0.00392156862745098, 0.0156862745098039, 0.0313725490196078, 
0.105882352941176, 0.305882352941176, 0.490196078431373, 0.56078431372549, 
0.615686274509804, 0.592156862745098, 0.505882352941176, 0.364705882352941, 
0.227450980392157, 0.0509803921568627, 0.0313725490196078, 0.0196078431372549, 
0.0549019607843137, 0.0313725490196078, 0.0156862745098039, 0.0274509803921569, 
0.00392156862745098, 0.0117647058823529)
plot(r)
```

[image]

I would like to find a gaussian that is as close as possible to the plot/data.

I tried with normalmixEM from the R package mixtools.

```
> fit = normalmixEM(r)
```

but this seems to try to fit to a mix of two gaussian by default.

I tried to specify that there is only one gaussian using the parameter k:

```
> fit = normalmixEM(r, k = 1)
Error in normalmix.init(x = x, lambda = lambda, mu = mu, s = sigma, k = k,  : 
  arbmean and arbvar cannot both be FALSE
```

How can I fit the data?

Comment: r is clearly not normal. Its distribution is right skewed (lot of small values close to 0, few large values). You will see this by typing "hist(r)".

Comment: Tip! Use `dput(r)` to generate a string that is easily copy'n'pasteable. Now we have to enter the data in r manually...

Comment: @RasmusBååth thanks, I was looking for that command :) I edited the question.

Comment: You don't plot a _sequence_ of data values to see the distribution. Does $r$ _already_ represent a frequency or probability density of data values?

Comment: I have answered this question several times in several contexts.  An `R` solution for a discrete variable like your `Index` appears at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43004/919; an `R` solution for a continuous variable is at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70153/linear-regression-best-polynomial-or-better-approach-to-use/70184#70184; and an Excel solution is at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11563/919.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a difference between fitting a gaussian *distribution* and fitting a gaussian *density curve*. What `normalmixEM` is doing is the former. What you want is (I guess) the latter.

Fitting a distribution is, roughly speaking, what you'd do if you made a histogram of your data, and tried to see what sort of shape it had. What you're doing, instead, is simply plotting a curve. That curve happens to have a hump in the middle, like what you get by plotting a gaussian density function.

To get what you want, you can use something like `optim` to fit the curve to your data. The following code will use nonlinear least-squares to find the three parameters giving the best-fitting gaussian curve: `m` is the gaussian mean, `s` is the standard deviation, and `k` is an arbitrary scaling parameter (since the gaussian density is constrained to integrate to 1, whereas your data isn't).

```
x <- seq_along(r)

f <- function(par)
{
    m <- par[1]
    sd <- par[2]
    k <- par[3]
    rhat <- k * exp(-0.5 * ((x - m)/sd)^2)
    sum((r - rhat)^2)
}

optim(c(15, 2, 1), f, method="BFGS", control=list(reltol=1e-9))
```

Comment: Played around with this solution but you beat me :) When playing around I noticed that the initial starting values given to `optim` mattered *a lot*, so when using this method make sure to check the fit graphically.

Answer (score 11):

I propose to use [non-linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares) for this analysis.

```
# First present the data in a data-frame
tab <- data.frame(x=seq_along(r), r=r)
#Apply function nls
(res <- nls( r ~ k*exp(-1/2*(x-mu)^2/sigma^2), start=c(mu=15,sigma=5,k=1) , data = tab))
```

And from the output, I was able to obtain the following fitted "Gaussian curve":

```
v <- summary(res)$parameters[,"Estimate"]
plot(r~x, data=tab)
plot(function(x) v[3]*exp(-1/2*(x-v[1])^2/v[2]^2),col=2,add=T,xlim=range(tab$x) )
```

[image]

The fit is not amazing... Wouldn't a $x \mapsto \sin(x) / x$ function be a better model?

Comment: Thanks. I get residual sum-of-squares: 0.01997. I think I am getting exactly the same with the solution from Hong Ooi above. Is the algo the same? Also how do I plot the result of nls?

Comment: Yeah, the algorithms are the same in the sense that if they work (don't get stuck in some local minimum) they give the same answer. Depending on the value given to `method=` they can be exactly the same.

Comment: I added two lines to generate the plot.

Comment: Likely to be a \$\sin^2(x)/x\$ as the data appears to be from an image. Would have been better if the OP didn't allow the jpeg compression to do its lossy maggic